# Float forms inside a well

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put 2 forms in a well one next to other. I use twitter-boostrap.

This is my code

```
      <div class="well">
          <h3>
            Title
          </h3>
          <form  method="post" class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="select01">Label1: </label> 
              <select class="input-mini" id="select01">
                      (my options)
              </select>
            </div>
              <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="input01">Label2: </label> 
                <input class="input-mini" id="input01">
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="select02">Label3: </label> 
              <select class="input-mini" id="select02">
                (myoptions)
              </select>
            </div>
          <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
          </form>
          <form  method="post" class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="input02">Label3: </label> 
                  <input class="input-mini" id="input02">
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="input03">Label4: </label> 
                  <input class="input-mini" id="input03">
              </div>
          <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>

          </form>
</div>
```

If I include the forms in divs and add a style with float:left, then my well brake and put my forms out of it. I tried span, divs, form inside a form, but I cannot find a way to put one form next to other without break the well.

Comment: Here's a starting-point fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/SAdM8/

Comment: Here is if I add the divs and how well breaks http://jsfiddle.net/SAdM8/2/

Comment: Add "overflow:hidden" to the well div. Should fix it.

Comment: Thank you. Both your suggestions work the same!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try wrapping your forms in a div to isolate that content from the well:

http://jsfiddle.net/SAdM8/6

```
<div class="well">
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    ... forms ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Like Billy Moat said, you could simply add the overflow property to the well. I prefer to keep Bootstrap elements in their natural state to avoid inadvertent breakage. Either works.

Comment: That's why I love stack overflow. Thank you both!